# Using SciPy optimize to fit one curve to many data series

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have many days of hourly mean temperatures. These have all been normalised so that the minimum and maximum daily temperature equal 0 and 1 respectively, with each of the hourly mean temperatures being scaled to this range.

```
df
[out]:
    Date_time   00:00   01:00   02:00   03:00   04:00   05:00   06:00   07:00   08:00   09:00   10:00   11:00   12:00   13:00   14:00   15:00   16:00   17:00   18:00   19:00   20:00   21:00   22:00   23:00   Max     Min
0   2019-02-03  0.0875  0.0868  0.0440  0.0120  0.0108  0.0461  0.0961  0.2787  0.4908  0.6854  0.7379  0.8615  0.9284  0.8488  0.7711  0.2200  0.1617  0.2376  0.2211  0.1782  0.1700  0.1736  0.1174  0.1389  25.7    17.9
1   2019-03-07  0.0432  0.0432  0.0126  0.0011  0.0054  0.0065  0.0121  0.0592  0.2799  0.4322  0.7461  0.7475  0.8130  0.8599  0.6245  0.4815  0.4641  0.3502  0.2126  0.1878  0.1988  0.2114  0.2168  0.2292  21.6    17.9
2   2019-04-21  0.0651  0.0507  0.0324  0.0198  0.0703  0.0454  0.0457  0.2019  0.3700  0.5393  0.6593  0.7556  0.8682  0.9374  0.9593  0.9110  0.8721  0.6058  0.4426  0.3788  0.3447  0.3136  0.2564  0.1414  29.3    15.1
```

I wish to use SciPy optimize to fit a curve to the hourly pattern of temperature. I can't fit a curve to the full time series dataset because:

- I want the fit to be generic, and applicable to any given day
- The data is discontinuous, meaning that there would be gaps in the dataset that would cause poor fit

When plotting the full dataset up, this is the result:

[image: Scatter plot of normalised hourly mean temperature]

It is to this that I'd like to fit a curve to, but all the examples on [SciPy](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy.html#optimization-and-fit-scipy-optimize) use datasets where there is only one value given for any time interval.

One option could be to calculate the mean for each hour and apply SciPy optimize to that. Is there another function I could use to apply a fit to the full dataset in Python?

Comment: Statistically, fitting a curve to the entire set of points would be identical to fitting a curve to the mean value for each hour.  Right?  The curve you got for the first set would try to minimize the per-hour error, and you do that by fitting to the mean.

Comment: ^ Might depend on whether you have the same number of observations at each hour, but weighting _could_ deal with any differences. AFAIK scipy.curve_fit is parametric, so you need to specify the functional form, allowing for some free parameters you optimize the fit with respect to. If you don't want to pre-suppose a functional form, there are some nonparametric curve-fitting methods like lowess, but those come with their own assumptions about the data

Comment: Yes, it could well be the same, statistics isn't my strong suit. I'm going to test the polynomial answer below on the full dataset, as well as fitting against the means, and I'll assess the RMSE for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned there are many ways to fit the data. and it depends on your assumptions and what you are trying to do. Here is an example of doing a simple polynomial fit to your sample data.

First load and massage the data

```
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = StringIO('''
    Date_time   00:00   01:00   02:00   03:00   04:00   05:00   06:00   07:00   08:00   09:00   10:00   11:00   12:00   13:00   14:00   15:00   16:00   17:00   18:00   19:00   20:00   21:00   22:00   23:00   Max     Min
0   2019-02-03  0.0875  0.0868  0.0440  0.0120  0.0108  0.0461  0.0961  0.2787  0.4908  0.6854  0.7379  0.8615  0.9284  0.8488  0.7711  0.2200  0.1617  0.2376  0.2211  0.1782  0.1700  0.1736  0.1174  0.1389  25.7    17.9
1   2019-03-07  0.0432  0.0432  0.0126  0.0011  0.0054  0.0065  0.0121  0.0592  0.2799  0.4322  0.7461  0.7475  0.8130  0.8599  0.6245  0.4815  0.4641  0.3502  0.2126  0.1878  0.1988  0.2114  0.2168  0.2292  21.6    17.9
2   2019-04-21  0.0651  0.0507  0.0324  0.0198  0.0703  0.0454  0.0457  0.2019  0.3700  0.5393  0.6593  0.7556  0.8682  0.9374  0.9593  0.9110  0.8721  0.6058  0.4426  0.3788  0.3447  0.3136  0.2564  0.1414  29.3    15.1
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+')
df2 = df.copy()
del df2['Date_time']
del df2['Max']
del df2['Min']
```

Extract the underlying hours and observatiobs, put into flattened arrays

```
hours = [dt.strptime(ts, '%H:%M').hour for ts in df2.columns]
raw_data = df2.values.flatten()
hours_rep = np.tile(hours, df2.values.shape[0])
```

Fit a polynomial of degree `deg` (set below to 6). This will do a best-fit as input data has multiple observations for the same hour

```
deg = 6
p = np.polyfit(hours_rep, raw_data, deg = deg)
fit_data = np.polyval(p, hours)
```

Plot the results

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(hours, df2.values.T, '.', label = 'obs')
plt.plot(hours, fit_data, 'o-', label = 'fit')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

This is how it looks like
[image]

Comment: This very much works, thank you. Even with the full dataset, you still get that uptick at the start. I've repeated the timeseries, which gets rid of the uptick for the repeat/second set of data, and it's looking really good